# Oh no, not again

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, acrostic

I wanted to say something, but I forget what it was. Can you help me?

> 10 - [A-z] (-2)
>
> 255 - #beginningfirst00
>
> 15 - Period.
>
> 0 - You forgot one. You forgot one. Since every beginning has an end,
> let's pave the way.
>
> 1 - I'm on repeat.
>
> 7 - Zelda's legend. I hear Link is quite the musician.
>
> 5 - Lester lists the lesser lesson last.
>
> 64 - 08,21,56,W
>
> 44 - June 5th Day.
>
> 33 - “For him?” shouted Snape. “Expecto Patronum!” “After all this
> time?”
>
> 8 - Tulips on a tree?!
>
> 21 - Monday, the sun will fly south for the winter.

***Hint***:

> I'm pretty sure D-Day was in here somewhere. Also, if I remember correctly, the first one is H, but I don't remember how to prove it.

***Hint***:

> I know for a fact the empty line speaks of two, was it before or after? I don't remember.

Comment: I'm not surprised you forgot - your mnemonic is too cryptic!

Comment: @lxop lol I wouldn't say so, I'm just too busy with work right now to solve it! The answer only requires about a 75% solution with an educated guess, but a 100% solution would be bounty worthy for sure. Explaining the numbering system is probably the hardest part to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full answer:

> The Message is Happy Holidays

10 - [A-z] (-2) is

> H because 8th letter in the Alphabet ( 10-2 is 8)

255 - #beginningfirst00

> 255 converts to ff and bf is the intials of before first #ffbf00 is the colour Amber

15 - Period.

> PHOSPHOROUS which is 15 on the periodic table.

0 - You forgot one. You forgot one. Since every beginning has an end, let's pave the way.

> Basically this is just hinting at the letters P and Y. Hap Holidays needs those two letters to complete it. Letters P and Y pave the way.

1 - I'm on repeat.Thanks to lxop for this

> H is the answer. Because it is 1 letter and it is a repeat of the first puzzle.

7 - Zelda's legend. I hear Link is quite the musician.

> This hints at the 7 Letter word OCARINA which is a musical instrument and part of the title of a Legend of Zelda game.

5 - Lester lists the lesser lesson last.

> The letter L because it appears 5 times in the sentence.

64 - 08,21,56,W

> Hinting at the song Reykjavík (64° 08' N 21° 56' W) by Kristjan Hrannar. Maybe the word you are looking for is ICELAND.

44 - June 5th Day.

> 1944 June the 5th was Eisenhowers selected date for the D-DAY invasions.

33 - “For him?” shouted Snape. “Expecto Patronum!” “After all this time?”

> A passage in Chapter 33 of the Deathly Hallows. ALBUS Dumbledore says "After all this time".

8 - Tulips on a tree?!

> You are probably referring to the 8th letter of the word KENTUCKY which is Y, the tulip tree is Kentucky's state tree.

21 - Monday, the sun will fly south for the winter.

> Monday 21st of December 2020 is the Winter SOLSTICE.

And so you have

> H, AMBER, PHOSPHOROUS, P and Y, H, OCARINA, L, ICELAND, D-DAY, ALBUS, Y, SOLSTICE.

Comment: Going great so far! 10 is correct, 255 is wrong (and difficult, think rot13(pbybe)), 15 the latter is correct, 1 is wrong, 44 is correct, 8 is wrong though a focused answer is what you're looking for so you're on the right track, 21 is correct but takes the latter word rot13(fbyfgvpr) instead of the full thing. Keep up the hard work, you're almost there!

Comment: Closing in on it. For 255, try rot13(pbairefvba), 0 has you thinking properly, but try applying that same logic to the line itself (adding a hint). Where is 64 and where is 8 important? Once you find 8, apply some logic from 7. 33 for life. :D

Comment: I dunno, is it? ;) You're on the write track with your current answer, the answer is there.

Comment: 255, other way.

Comment: FF is closer to the answer now. ;)

Comment: @Tacoタコス Where is the answer at now (as of Revision #21)? i.e. what's left to solve?

Comment: Are you working ln this too?

Comment: @Smartest1here I don't really care to take a crack at it if I'd have to chase down what's currently correct or not. Have at!

Comment: I'm following along, but don't have enough for my own answer. I have a suggestion though: for `1`, it could be rot13(*Gur yrggre U, juvpu vf ercrngrq sebz gur svefg (urapr '1') pyhr*)

Comment: Ah yes could be.

Comment: @lxop is correct there. Regarding where it's at, 255 is still wrong, but here's a hint rot13(ss ortvavat svefg 00 naq vg unf n anzr). 0 is hard as it gives two answers, the first is what you're missing, the second is what you need, both are repeated, but in different ways. The latter of the two is repeated inline. The former you'll find as you write the full answer, but is explained in line 0. 8 has the right word now, but the number 8 serves two purposes there. For 33, what comes next? The rest are all correct, currently giving an acrostic of rot13(U?C? ?BYVQ??F).

Comment: I think I have solved it now.

Comment: Looks awesome! 33 is technically rot13(Nyjnlf) which is rot13(Fancr'f erfcbafr gb "Nsgre nyy guvf gvzr?"), but the conclusion you arrived at is acceptable :) great work!